# how to correlate onclick mouse position to exact DOM element content?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, click

Using jquery I try to create a plugin which can do the following: given an arbitrary webpage which is mostly text-based like wikipedia or such. Basically I'm talking about plain HTML rendered by the browser. Now, if the user clicks somewhere on the website, like in the middle of an interesting sentence (or word) of a text passage, the plugin detects this click - at this point I think I'm talking about a simple `onclick` event.

What I now want to do is: the plugin not only knows that the user clicked but also exactly where within the DOM tree. this means for example that i want to know that the click is correlated to a span-element which contains a string AND within that string the user clicked between character 4 and 5.

I found an image which shows pretty good [what I try to do](http://developer.android.com/sdk/images/2.3/selection.png).

With such a plugin there are plenty of things one can do like: highlight some text like you do when learning from a book or create highlighted correlations between text passages on different websites, ...
but currently i'm just thinking about how I could gather the data needed for visualization within the browser

thx for any hint on this

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for clicks anywhere in a document by starting with something like:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).click(function(evt) {
        var elementClicked = evt.target;
        var xCoordinate = evt.pageX;
        var yCoordinate = evt.pageY;

        alert('You clicked a ' + elementClicked.tagName + 
            ' at {' + xCoordinate + ',' + yCoordinate + '}');

        // Do work to figure out what the element was and where within it was clicked
        switch (elementClicked.tagName.toLowerCase()) {
            case "input":
            case "span":
            case "button":
            case "label":
            case "select":
            case "textarea":
            case "p":
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

The problem there is anything else that had an `onclick` event needs to prevent the event from propagating to your "master" click handler.

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/consultcory/bBvy4/1/) to get you started.

Comment: the usage of getSelection from your JSFiddle seems worth a look. At least Firefox's window.getSelection() provides a few interesting properties - not yet sure which will do it